# Takes no arguments, 2 given: Kivy Button bind to def

Tags: python, kivy

Error:

> TypeError: changetxt() takes no arguments but 2 given, or global name play_btn not defined.

I tried adding instance, self as well into the def args but still have the same error.

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder

class launchScreenMenu(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(launchScreenMenu, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        menuanchor = AnchorLayout(anchor_x='left',anchor_y='bottom')
        menu = StackLayout(orientation='bt-lr',size_hint=(0.5,1))
        about_btn = Button(text='About',size_hint=(0.3,0.1))
        help_btn = Button(text='Settings',size_hint=(0.3,0.1))
        settings_btn = Button(text='Help',size_hint=(0.3,0.1))

        menu.add_widget(about_btn)
        menu.add_widget(help_btn)
        menu.add_widget(settings_btn)
        menuanchor.add_widget(menu)
        return self.add_widget(menuanchor)

class launchScreenBtn(AnchorLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(launchScreenBtn, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        play_btn = Button(text="Play")
        self.anchor_x = 'center'
        self.anchor_y = 'center'
        self.size_hint = 0.2,0.2
        self.add_widget(play_btn)
        play_btn.bind(on_press=self.changetxt)

    def changetxt():
        play_btn.text = 'Game Over'


class GameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = AnchorLayout()
        root.add_widget(launchScreenMenu())
        root.add_widget(launchScreenBtn())
        return root

if __name__=='__main__':
    GameApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of instance methods (think any function in a class, but there are exceptions) is a link to the instance itself. By convention this is called `self`. [Reference](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects)

I don't know with 100% certainty what your second argument is. It may be `play_btn` since that's what's calling the function. That would be convenient since you're trying to reference that anyway, and it otherwise would be undefined.

How you want your def to read is like this:

```
def changetxt(self, play_btn):
```

Comment: Cheers :) that works, and thanks for the reference, for some reason classes and oop really confuse me,  procedural and general functions I think im ok lol

Answer (score 3):

All instance methods should always has `self` as their first argument:

```
def changetxt(self, *args):
    self.play_btn = 'Game Over'
```

`*args` is just to be secure, in case it wasn't you who pass the argument.

Also, change *all* `play_btn` inside the class to `self.play_btn`:

```
self.play_btn = Button(text="Play")
```

Well, hope this helps!

Comment: Might need to add def changetext(self, *args)  and then see what that second argument actually is

Comment: @theodox Ah yeah. kivy might just do that. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, Helpful for understanding, changing it to self,args and self.play_button results in launchscreenbtn has no object attribute play_button, I tried  mhlester code adjust and that seems to work tho, thanks for the help :)